# jquery change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery change event that is working fine apart from an addition I just made. What I am trying to do, is when a user selects anything other than 'NEW' from the select, then show an input element. I assumed that this would work with just an else statement, but I was wrong. I would be grateful if someone could check my code and show me where I am going wrong? Thanks

```
<!--- dropdown for new user addition  -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


        $(function() {

        $("#fld_company").show();
        $("#data").hide();


        $("#fld_company").live('click', function() {
              $("#fld_fld").toggle(1000);
              $("#formMessage").toggle(1000);
        });

            $("#AUSR_company").live('change', function() {
              if($(this).val()=="new")

             {
                $("#data").slideDown(1000);

             }

        else

           {

            $("#AUSR_name").show().slideDown(1000);

           }
        });
    });

</script>
<!--- end of dropdown for new user addition -->

        <dl>
          <dt>
            <label for="AUSR_name" class="opt">Full Name:</label>
          </dt>
         <dd>
            <input id="AUSR_name" name="AUSR_name" type="text" size="32" maxlength="128" value = "" />
         </dd>
        </dl>
```

Comment: please put the full code. where are 'fld_company', 'data', 'fld_fld', 'formMessage', 'AUSR_company'. if one of these elements are missing your code may fail.

Comment: @chamika There is no code missing. I only posted the relevant parts. Thanks

Comment: when you referring jQuery 1.5.0+ version. if you set `display:none` for `data`, `$("#data").slideDown(1000);` not show anything. you can try `display:block` before  `$("#data").slideDown(1000);` or just use `$("#data").show();`

Comment: @Chamika Please see my latest comment to Liam. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @bollo, did you try my latest answer, with stopPropagation()?

Comment: @liam getting e is not defined. thanks

Comment: @liam missed the e in the function. no error, but still not working. Thanks

Comment: @liam i have added code to your code and when I do console.log($(this).val()); I can see the correct values coming through.

Comment: @liam as a stop gap, I just wrapped the input in it's own div. Not really what I wanted to do and cannot see why your solution would not work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment, the below is what you need, but I have already seen that this is what you said wasn't working in the question. PLease explain in what way it wasn't working?

```
$("#AUSR_company").live('change', function(e) {
  if($(this).val() =="new") {
    $("#data").show();

  } else {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#AUSR_name").show(3000)
  }
});
```

Comment: liam I assumed that was the reason for the show function I already know it is using the hide function. Can you do example based on my code for showing #AUSR_name when the #AUSR_company is !='new'. thanks

Comment: I have changed my answer, but I don't know if this is what you mean. AUSR_company is a dropdown? and when it is changed you want to show AUSR_name only if the user selects new for AUSR_company? If this is not the case please edit your question to explain clearly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: liam thank you for that, but I am still struggling to see the logic. All I am trying to do is, if a user selects anything other than 'new' show the div #AUSR_name. However, if the user selects 'new' then I show the div #data. Thanks

Comment: liam I do not need to see #data only the #AUSR_name element in it. I only show #data when a user selects 'new'. Thanks

Comment: liam. I have just looked at your latest update and your code is the same as my original code. Apart from the slideDown to show. Thanks

Comment: Stop propagation should stop it from showing all of the data div, thereby leaving only the AUSR_name elemeent showing. try that.

Comment: Liam I shall accept your answer because it showed me another way to implement what I am trying to do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `.click()` and `.change()` instead? You can read more about them here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: Proapbly because he will be adding and removing those inputs alot and doesn't want to rebind them manually each time.

Comment: Oh alright, fair enough. I'll leave my response here though, so that he too can respond to the inquiry. :-)

Comment: @ninetwozero Daniel was correct but thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have `AUSR_company` input element in your form

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("#AUSR_company").live('change', function() {
```

should be

```
        $("#AUSR_name").live('change', function() {
```